# Nesting function calls in Powershell

Tags: powershell, functional-programming

I'm exploring functional programming in powershell and I'm having an issue executing nested functions:

```
function Get-ThreadsafeMessageAction {
    param(
        [System.Threading.Mutex] $mutex,
        $action)
        $mtx = $mutex
        $act = $action
    return { param([string] $message)
        $mtx.WaitOne()
        &$act $message
        $mtx.ReleaseMutex()}
}
```

Error:

```
The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. 
It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\myscript.ps1:21 char:52
+         Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param($act) & $act $message } -A ...
+                                                    ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression
```

Comment: `return {...}.GetNewClosure()`

Comment: @PetSerAl can you add this as answer and I can give you credit?